# Reducing GPS points based on Speed

Tags: r, performance, gps, distance, spatial

I am trying to delete the points of longitude and Latitude on the basis of Speed. If speed is not within the range of given threshold then add the terminating longitude and Latitude pair in the vector, Else ignore it and move to next points of longitude and Latitude. But my code is not working. 
Below is the code;

```
 while (i < length(longitude))
{
 library(geosphere)
 dist <- distm (c(longitude [j],Latitude[j]), c(longitude [i],Latitude[i]), 
 fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)
 distt <- append(distt, dist)
 time_vector <- time[j] - time[i]
 time_TT <- append(time_TT, time_vector*60)  # converting mints into seconds 
 speed <- distt/time_TT                      # Calculating speed 

 if!((speed <= speed + delta) & (speed >= speed - delta))

 {
  LON_S  <- append(LON_Speed, longitude [j])
  LAT_S  <- append(LAT_Speed, Latitude[j])

   }
   else break;
   i <- j 
   j <- i + 1
   }


 Data is 

 longitude <- round(c(48.7188021250007,
                 48.7188133749999,
                 48.7188291249998,
                 48.7188336250004, 
                 48.7188291250005, 
                 48.7188291250085
                 ), 8);

 Latitude <- round(c (2.39514523661229,
                 2.39512477447308, 
                 2.39472235230961,
                 2.39467460730213,
                 2.39467460730313, 
                 2.4), 8);

  time <- strptime(c('2017-04-06 09:15:00',
               '2017-04-06 09:30:00',
               '2017-04-06 09:40:00',
               '2017-04-06 09:50:00',
               '2017-04-06 09:55:00',
               '2017-04-06 10:56:00'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition for checking the speed range is always false. LAssuming `delta` and `speed` are both positive values, `speed` is always less then (or equals) to `speed + delta`, so

```
if!((speed <= speed + delta) & (speed >= speed - delta))
```

The first condition is `speed <= speed + delta` which is always true.
Similarly, `speed >= speed + delta` is always true so inside the parentheses you always end up with `true`. Next you apply the `not` operator so you always get `false`.
You have to something like this:

```
MAX <- your maximum allowed speed 
MIN <- your minimum allowed speed
if ((speed >= MIN) & (speed <= MAX))
{
   #speed is within range
}
else
{
   #speed is outside the range
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply.